# eliminar alert no configurado

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

tengo un problemilla que no sé cómo solucionar, a ver si me podeis ayudar.

En una ventana tengo una ventana la cual tiene los datos personales y otros datos de una persona en la cual tiene un enlace "Modificar" que me lleva al formulario de modificar los datos, pero dicho enlace te redirige al formulario de modificar de la web antigua.

El tema es que cuando doy al enlace para ir a modificar los datos me aparece un alert, el cual yo no lo he puesto y según el navegador en el que estés te pone un texto distinto, y no sé por qué me sale dicho alert, en Chrome me aparece el alert que pone "Realmente quiere salir del sitio web? los cambios no se han guardado" en firefox pone algo parecido pero con otras palabras, le doy a cancelar para no salir de la ventana, pero si le doy una segunda vez, ya no me salta el alert y me redirige bien a la ventana de modificar de la web antigua. El tema es que dicho alert no debería aparecer ya que en sí yo no lo he puesto y me imagino que es tema de los navegadores y no sé si hay alguna función o algo para desactivarlo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: En la ventana que tiene otra ventana, ese botón de **Modificar** ¿es un control de formulario verdad? y ¿en qué lenguaje estáis haciendo el backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El *Alert* que ves está disparado por el evento [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) de JavaScript, cada navegador, y versión de navegador tiene una implementación distinta, por eso cambia el texto, si no quieres verlo mas **busca ese texto en todo el proyecto y lo borras, con la función que esté añadida**. Puede aparecer como `onbeforeunload="algunaFuncion()"`, como  `object.onbeforeunload = function(){//codigo}` o `object.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){//codigo});`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya encontré la función **onbeforeunload**, la comenté (antes de borrarla) y era eso, ya está solucionado. Muchas gracias, un saludo